# delete one file inside a tar.gz file and compress the archive again

Tags: python, compression, extract, archive, tarfile

I have a file tar.gz and I want to extract it then delete the file that starts with "net_" then compress the files again with the same name:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys, getopt
import tarfile
import glob
import tempfile
import shutil
import json
import urllib
import boto3
import logging


key = 'file_14747.tar.gz'
filepath = os.path.join('/tmp/', key)
if os.path.basename(filepath).startswith('file_'):
  file_key = tarfile.open(filepath, "w:gz")
  file_key.extractall()
  file_key.close()
# suppression de fichier net
for file in os.listdir("/tmp/"):
  if file.startswith('net_'):
    os.remove(file)
# compresser les fichiers
tar = tarfile.open('/tmp/'+key, "w:gz")
for file_name in os.listdir("/tmp/"):
  print(file_name)
  if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
    print(" Adding %s..." % file_name)
    tar.add(file_name, os.path.basename(file_name))
tar.close()
```

I tried this but everytime I get an empty file.tar.gz and I lose all the files and I don't get what I want.
How to open the archive, delete the one file and compress the archive again?

Comment: what is your current directory? is it `/tmp` or something else?

Comment: In fact, I am running this script in AWS Lambda, so I only get to work in /tmp/ folder.

Comment: Uncompressing the file probably creates a separate directory under `/tmp` under which all files are located.

Comment: note that `for file_name in os.listdir("/tmp/"):` yields only the basenames of the files.`. Maybe you need `os.walk` or `glob.glob("/tmp/**")`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre is right, when deleting the file you need to make sure to use the absolute file path. The same holds for the second `for` loop (which adds the files to the archive). Here you can also use `glob.glob('/tmp/*.csv')` (requires `import glob`). It allows for wildcards and returns the absolute paths.